# txt file won't be written in python in windows, it works on mac

Tags: python, windows, artificial-intelligence

I wrote a code that takes a video and recognizes face of a human and calculate the distance of the human from the camera (which is the eye of a robot). I need the data in a txt format so I am writing it in the distance_data.txt but my file is always empty.
I had run the code in a mac computer and it worked perfectly fine and the file was not empty.

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

person_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('human_recognition.txt')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('oct23_2.avi')

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('oct23_2out.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,360))

distance_data = open('distance_data.txt','w')

timer=-1
while (cap.isOpened()):
 r, frame = cap.read()
 if r:

    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(640,360)) # Downscale to improve frame rate
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # Haar-cascade classifier needs a grayscale image
    cv2.imshow('gray',gray_frame)
    #print(gray_frame.type())
    rects = person_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_frame)
    max=0
    #print(rects)

    (x, y, w, h) = rects[0]
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w ,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    #fshape = frame.shape
    #fheight = fshape[0]
    #fwidth = fshape[1]
    timer=timer+1
    xpos=(0.03421)*(w*w)-8.1183*w+521.841
    yn=360-y
    heightinvid=0.0197377*yn-0.0194
    realhieght=((-0.4901)*(heightinvid* heightinvid)+4.4269*heightinvid+8.30356)/ 0.927183854

    horizontalp=x+w/2



    #print(timer+1 , ",", xpos, )
    #if (xpos<=41 and xpos>=40):
    #print("height of the human is ", realhieght+149, "or", (-0.000184)*yn*yn+0.08506*yn+8.43461+149)
    cm_deviation_in_x=-0.02033898*(320-horizontalp)
    #print("Horizontal position of human is ", cm_deviation_in_x, " cm.")
    newxpos = format (xpos, '.3f')
    distance_data.write("Hi")
    distance_data.write(str(newxpos))
    distance_data.write(',')
    distance_data.write(str(format(cm_deviation_in_x, '.3f')))
    distance_data.write("\r\n")

    #print(w)
    #print("x position of the human is = ",xpos)
        #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        #out = cv2.VideoWriter('output25.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (fwidth,fheight))

    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    out.write(frame)

 k = cv2.waitKey(10)
 #print(w,h)
 if k & 0xFF == ord("q"): # Exit condition
    break
distance_data.flush()
cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Are you sure this is even a writing problem?  Do you know for sure the capture file is being *read* properly in Windows?  Does it exist?  Do you actually enter the while loop?  Do you make it past the "if r:" statement?

Comment: don't write carriage return, it's automatically added in text mode `distance_data.write("\r\n")` => `distance_data.write("\n")`

Comment: yes I do enter the loop because I could print all the data in the console. I do however get this error at the end:      (x, y, w, h) = rects[0]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
 @PhilB

Comment: also `distance_data.flush()` should be `distance_data.close()`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I actually don't know where I should close the file

Comment: where you flushed it is good.

Comment: Where are you getting the out of range error?  That may be what is stopping everything.  Are the versions of python and all other libraries the same on OSX and Windows?